# Unicode characters are displayed wrong in bash

Tags: bash, unicode

I'm using [powerline-shell](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell) as my bash's `PS1`. But as you can see in the screenshot, the unicode characters aren't displayed correctly:

[image: screenshot]

How do I make unicode characters be printed correctly in Bash?

**Edit:**

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Which characters don't render correctly? What do you expect to see?

Comment: @tripleee - Here are some of the characters it's trying to display - '\uE0A2', '\uE0B0', '\uE0B1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [instructions](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell#setup) mention that you need to patch your console font, which apparently you have not done (successfully); or perhaps you have failed to set up your terminal to use one of the patched fonts.

Since your question fails to mention anything about this, I think it's safe to assume that you simply missed this part of the instructions.

According to [your comment,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704348/unicode-characters-are-displayed-wrong-in-bash/704541#comment1034454_704348) the characters which are displaying incorrectly are e.g. [U+E0A2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0a2/index.htm), [U+E0B0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0b0/index.htm), and [U+E0B1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0b1/index.htm).  But those are ["private use area" characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/private_use_area/index.htm), so they don't have any universal meaning.  There is no "correct" or "incorrect" here as far as Unicode is concerned, just lack of standardization.

Answer (score 0):

Try install fonts-powerline first

```
sudo apt install fonts-powerline
```